# encypted pasword for Tomcat server.xml JDBC Datasource

Tags: tomcat7, jdbc

I have certain JDBC resources configured in my Tomcat **server.xml** file. Using those, I can connect remote databases.

*For example*

```
<Resource name="jdbc/hox" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
                    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                    url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.223/db123?autoReconnect=true"
                    username="hox" password="hox123" maxTotal="10" maxIdle="5"
                    maxWaitMillis="10000" validationQuery="Select 1"  />
```

Now I would prefer to use encrypted password rather using plain text password "hox123".

I have searched many blog posts but nothing seems to be providing me complete details. I am still not sure whether it is possible or not.

Comment: How would the password be decrypted before use?

Comment: The solution must be provided either by Tomcat or MySQL